# Desire to upgrade Ubuntu to 19.10 - Can't get unetbootin (Current Version == 18.04)

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa, 19.10, unetbootin

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu version to 19.10. I saw no direct way, so I'm trying to mount the iso (which I have downloaded) onto a usb. It seems I need software like Unetbootin to do that, but when I try to run the usual commands found on the internet:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

I get an error after the first command telling me the directory doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two tested & supported upgrade paths; (1) to the next release which was 18.10, or (2) to the next LTS which will be 20.04 when it reaches the 20.04.1 stage due later this year.  Your other supported (& tested) alternative is to re-install with 19.10; you can use 'something-else', use your existing partitions & not-format them, it'll erase system dirs, install, add back your additional packages (if available on new release) then request reboot. It won't erase your files (unless you format), nor configs if in $HOME or desktop, but server configs are in system directories..

Comment: I don't know how to do all that & I need 19.10 for a class I'm taking. Any resources to help me figure out how to do those steps?

Comment: Validate you Ubuntu ISO (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then write to media (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011), validate that step (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck; CD refers to whatever media you use, be it thumb-drive, ssd, hdd etc).  Install; I'd use the 'something-else' & select existing partitions; don't use 'format'. It'll note packages, erase system dirs, install, add back your additional packages & ask to reboot. It won't touch user files unless you selected format